# Number of Solutions

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

How to to calculate the number of solutions for the equation 
$A+B-\gcd(A,B)=R$
where we are given $R$ in the question ?
In this question we have to calculate the number of combinations of $A$ and $B$ which satisfies this equation.

Comment: If $d=(A,B)$ and $\frac Aa=\frac Bb=d\implies (a,b)=1$ we have $d(a+b-1)=R$ not sure if it helps

Answer (score 3):

For any divisor $g$ of $R$ you get a solution $(a+b-1)g=ag+bg-g=R$ for $a,b$ coprime. So we are interested in the number of ways you can write $\frac{R}{g}+1$ as a sum of coprime numbers.

Since $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,a+b)=\gcd(a,\frac{R}{g}+1)$ there are $\varphi(\frac{R}{g}+1)$ ways to do so (where $\varphi$ denotes Euler's totient function). Thus the answer is $$\sum_{d\mid R} \varphi(d+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

If I follow benh's logic correctly, then his answer is double counting (almost) all of the solutions. This would be a comment on his answer, but I fail the rep requirement and it turned out too long and detailed anyway.

Let $ f = \frac{R}{g} $

$ \gcd(a, f + 1) = 1. $ Thus if $ c > 1 $ divides a, it does not divide $ f + 1 $.

Let $ c > 1 $ divide a. Then c does not divide $ f+1 -a = b $, hence a and b are coprime if either of them is coprime with $ f+1 $.

Thus the conclusion follows that naturals less than and coprime with $ f + 1 $ correspond to solutions. But consider when $ a = f + 1 -k $. This forces $ b = k $, which gives an identical solution to when a is chosen as k, forcing $ b = f + 1 -k $. This means that any solution where $ a \not = f + 1 - a $ is being double counted.

$ a = f + 1 - a \implies f+1 = a + a \implies b = a$

Positive $ b = a $ are coprime only when $ b = a = 1 $, hence every case except for one solution is being double counted.

It then follows that the number of solutions is:

$$\frac{1 + \sum\limits_{d|R}\varphi(d+1)}{2}$$

Comment: It depends on your understanding of "number of combinations for $A$ and $B$. I interpret it as all pairs $(A,B)$ satisfying the condition, so $(A,B)$ and $(B,A)$ are distinct as long as $A\neq B$. You are right about your solution if instead of pairs we require sets $\{A,B\}$.

Comment: @benh Yeah, you're right. But 'combination' suggests order does not matter (and clearly gcd/addition are symmetric), so I figured it was important to clarify.